# Multiple class instances: __new__ and __init__

Tags: python, python-class

When I was learning python, I encountered the following problems, some doubts.

1. why `id(Foo.data)` is the same storage space, is this design to save memory, why `id(obj)` is two
2. such output results make me puzzled, such as why `id(obj)` is a fixed one, `data` is `[]`, etc.

I want to have a deeper understanding of object-oriented `__init__` and `__new__`, please help to answer, thx

1. run it:

```py
class Foo(object):
    data = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.data.append(1)

for i in range(3):
    obj = Foo()
    print("cls", id(obj))
    print("var", id(Foo.data))
    print(obj.data)
```

result:

```bash
cls 4371702544
var 4372960000
[1]
cls 4372574896
var 4372960000
[1, 1]
cls 4371702544
var 4372960000
[1, 1, 1]
```

2. Change it to the following and run it again

```py
class Foo(object):
    data = []
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls

    def __init__(self):
        self.data.append(1)

for i in range(3):
    obj = Foo()
    print("cls", id(obj))
    print("var", id(Foo.data))
    print(obj.data)
```

result

```bash
cls 5274455728
var 4374680448
[]
cls 5274455728
var 4374680448
[]
cls 5274455728
var 4374680448
[]
```

Comment: 2) and 3) don't create instances of `Foo` at all, because `__new__` returns `None`.

Comment: For 1) note: "class variables are declared *when a class is being constructed*. They are not defined inside any methods of a class because of this only one copy of the static variable will be created and shared between all objects of the class".

Answer (score 1):

1. `Foo` is a class, `Foo.data` is a class attribute. Since you have declared it this way, `Foo.data` is the same for all instances of `Foo`, even if you access it as an `obj.data`.
2. Looking at this snippet:

   ```
   obj = Foo()
   print("cls", id(obj))
   ```

   `obj` is not a class (like is suggested by "cls"), but an instance of class `Foo`.
3. You `__new__()` is broken, because it returns a class instead of an instance.  See the documentation: [Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).